# Configure gradle "maven-publish" plugin directly from my custom plugin

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

i'm new in gradle and want to create custom gradle plugin that applies `maven-publish` plugin. Also my plugin should configure `maven-publish` plugin so that another plugin user should do nothing. And my plugin will automaticly configure `maven-publish`. 
I've tried to find any same tutorial but doesn't find.
How can I configure `maven-publish` gradle plugin from my custom plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring other plugins from a custom plugin is extremely common. You should be able to reference any custom plugin out there for examples. For `maven-publish` specifically, I have created the following example:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.publish.PublishingExtension;
import org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication;
import org.gradle.api.publish.maven.plugins.MavenPublishPlugin;

import java.net.URI;

public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPluginManager().apply(MavenPublishPlugin.class);

        project.getExtensions().configure(PublishingExtension.class, publishing -> {
            publishing.repositories(repositories -> {
                repositories.maven(maven -> {
                   maven.setUrl(URI.create("https://my-publishing-repo.com"));
                });
            });
            publishing.publications(publications -> {
                publications.create("mavenJava", MavenPublication.class, mavenJava -> {
                    mavenJava.artifact(project.getTasks().named("bootJar"));
                });
            });
        });
    }

}
```

This is equivalent to the following in the Gradle build file (Kotlin DSL):

```
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://my-publishing-repo.com")
        }
    }
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            artifact(tasks.named("bootJar").get())
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to the following guides from my guidance:

- [Developing Custom Gradle Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html)
- [Implementing Gradle plugins](https://guides.gradle.org/implementing-gradle-plugins/)
- [Build Init Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html) -- for generating Gradle plugin project

Answer (score 0):

@Cisco's answer was helpful for me but I still struggled to translate the `apply` method to use the kotlin-dsl. I ended up with this

```
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
    
        project.pluginManager.apply(MavenPublishPlugin::class.java)
        project.extensions.configure<PublishingExtension> {
            repositories {
                repositories.maven {
                    url = URI.create("https://my-publishing-repo.com")
                }
            }
            publications {
                publications.create(
                    "mavenJava",
                    MavenPublication::class.java
                ) {
                    artifact(project.tasks.named("bootJar"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```